# pandas.Series.drop didn't work out for me

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
s = pd.Series(data=np.arange(3), index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'])
print(s)
```

I use the example from the pandas official documentation page. I tried to run it on Jupyter notebook and PyCharm, but both of them showed this:

```
A    0
B    1
C    2
dtype: int32
```

and I expect it to show this result(same as the documentation)

```
A  0
dtype: int64
```

My numpy is on ver1.20.3 and pandas is on ver1.2.4

Sorry for the basic question, just started to learn coding since last week.

Comment: reassign the dataframe, it _returns_ a soft copy with the labels dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `inplace=True` in the drop method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(data=np.arange(3), index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'], inplace=True)

print(s)

A    0
dtype: int64
```

Or assign the output of drop to the variable `s`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(data=np.arange(3), index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
s = s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'])

print(s)
A    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks the above method worked for me, but I don't understand why the official documentation didn't contain the "inplace=True" after "labels=['B', 'C']" and it works.

Comment: Indeed, in the examples of the official documentation they are not using the `inplace` argument but at the top you see all the arguments available and you have `inplace` mentioned cf https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop.html. You can display the documentation of the method easily in a jupyter notebook by running `s.drop??`. It is useful to quickly check all the arguments available!

Answer (score 1):

Either do

```
s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'], inplace=True)
```

or

```
s = s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
s = s.drop(labels=['B', 'C'], axis=1)